# use curl to pass file from one server to another

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I have a web server that receives a posted data form, one part of which can be an attached image.  I want to use curl to send that information along to a second server.  Everything works fine for requests that do not include an image, but when an image is included in the original post I get:

```
curl error 26: failed creating formpost data
```

I know this indicates that curl is unable to find the file, but I am having trouble determining exactly why not.  Here is the code

```
if ($_POST) {
  $postData = array();    
  //copy in the post fields that were posted here    
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $postData[$key] = $value;  
  }
  //copy in the files that have been included
  foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["tmp_name"]) { //if null, no file was uploaded              
      $fn = "existing_image.jpg";//(use existing for debugging only
                                 //in reality, would use the tmp image)           
      $postData[$key] = "@" . realpath($fn) . ";type=" . $value["type"];

      $testMsg .= "added file $key value of '" . $postData[$key] .
          "'(" . file_exists($fn) . ")\n";
    }
  }

  $testMsg .= "POSTDATA:\n" . print_r($postData, true);

  $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;        
  $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postData;  
}
```

And here is the output:

```
added file photo value of '@/var/www/wordpress/somedirectory/php/existing_image.jpg;type=image/jpeg'(1)
POSTDATA:
Array
(
    [key1] => 4
    [key2] => blah blah some text
    [key3] => etc
    [keyimage] => @/var/www/wordpress/somedirectory/php/existing_image.jpg;type=image/jpeg
)
```

The file indeed exists - why is curl giving me the error?  I appreciate any help you can give...

Edit:  I do not have this same problem when servers 1 and 2 are the same server (i.e. when I set up a web page on the second server that receives the posted data and then executes the same curl code to send the info along to itself).  That probably means something, but I am evidently overlooking something...

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct permission set on `/var/www/wordpress/somedirectory/php/` folder? If not you can try to set it to `chmod 777 /var/www/wordpress/somedirectory/php/existing_image.jpg`

Comment: @KristerAndersson thanks - that's a good idea, though I've tried it already.  permissions are normally 644 (which I would imagine should work), but even 777 doesn't work.  There are also global read permissions on each folder, and I can access existing_image.jpg over the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but perhaps you `php` or `curl` version doesn't support setting the content type this way. Try to remove the `type=` part from your code and let curl decide the content type:

```
$postData[$key] = "@" . realpath($fn);
```

You could also try setting the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` flag to true and see if you get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Removing the content type as you suggested did the trick.  However, the image now comes through on the receiving end as `application/octet-stream` which isn't ideal.  Other searches for *that* issue suggest including the content type as I had been doing.  I'd rather have the new problem than the original (really shouldn't be relying on the self-reported incoming mime types anyway), but I'd love to figure out what exactly the issue is.  Perhaps a curl version thing, as you suggest.

Comment: @susiederkins - It is hard to tell because your original code works just fine for me, but I think I had the same problem running an earlier version.